# OnClientClick not working First Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I am trying to open PDF file into new window on image button onClientClick event whenever i click on image button first time nothing will happen and when i try to click second time it will open the file into new window
i just want to open the file on first click

i used code that below mention.

```
//Find control in Grid view
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow (((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
 HiddenField hdnFileName = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdnFilePath");
 ImageButton ibtn = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("ibtnDownload");

//Get File Path and FileName and Concate
 string strFilePath = "\\OnlineContent\\";
 string filePath = strFilePath +"/"+ hdnFileName.Value;

//Open PDF file into new tab
 ibtn.OnClientClick = "window.open('"+filePath.ToString()+"','target=_blank');";
```

Comment: Are you aware that your string variable filePath is initialised as: "\\OnlineContent\\/{value}" ?

Comment: Using `window.open` is always a bad idea. A lot of browsers/plugins/virus scanners can block it.

Comment: Yes i am aware that @MasterYoda

Comment: @WeeZy But how does that even work? it either resolves as a filepath or a URL doesnt it? How can you use \\ and / together?

Comment: Ok @VDWWD any other option or link that can help me to open PDF file into browser not downloading just open that file into new tab

Comment: @MasterYoda if i dont do that then i got this type of URL
http://localhost:64691/OnlineContent**RK90AdmitCard.pdf**
in bold font this is my PDF File Name
therefor i explicitly add forward slash in my string

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint on the filePath variable and copy the value into your question for both times you click? id be interested to know what directory you are hitting

Comment: @MasterYoda Both time getting same filePath and second time file path working
but whenever i put brackpoint on file path and heat button second time first fire the event that means open the file and then going for debugging 
i think issue is not in First click or second click

Comment: If you make it a normal link `<a href="file.pfd" target="_blank">pdf</a>`, the browser will open a new window. However it is not guaranteed that the user sees it in the browser. that depend on his settings and the browser(plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Use .. (double dot) or ~ (tilde sign) before \OnlineContent.

string strFilePath = "\OnlineContent\";
string filePath = strFilePath +"/"+ hdnFileName.Value;